# is my Lenovo S103t compatible with touch screen compatible with ubuntu?

Tags: multi-touch

Can I install the latest version of ubuntu on my Netbook and will my touch screen work?

Answer (score 0):

Snowlinux 4 Cinnamon http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=07897 is alleged here (bottom of page)  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1415915&page=49 to work perfectly but there seem to be problems with standard Ubuntu as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/946417.